# Assign subdomain for new heroku process

Tags: node.js, heroku, subdomain, sails.js

I'm using node.js & sails. So I would like to spawn another heroku process, e.g. : 'node app2.js" and assign subdomain to it, app2.myherokuname.herokuapp.com

Is that possible? I'm looking for best practices to implement microservice architecture, so I could use common libs, modules, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible per-se. You can't create a sub-subdomain to your herokuapp.com subdomain.
However, you can create as many apps as you need on your account, and assign them custom domains.

Here your new process would be a new app for which you would assign the custom domain `x.y.example.com`.
Alternatively, if you don't want to use a custom domain, you can just name it `app2-myherokuappname.herokuapp.com`.

Comment: The reason why I asked, that I can easily spawn process from the same app dir.
1. main process: node app.js
2. second: node app2.js

I'm looking for way to bind http server for second one.

Comment: Maybe I can configure heroku router to redirect some requests to my second process.

Comment: No, you can't do that.